Is metric incompleteness of $\overline{X}$ always witnessed by some sequence in $X$?
This following conjecture seems intuitively true to me, but I have trouble proving it (and I haven't found it confirmed/disconfirmed in the literature or online):
Let $M$ be an incomplete metric space. If $X \subseteq M$ is such that $\overline{X}$ is incomplete, then some divergent Cauchy sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $\overline{X}$ has a divergent Cauchy subsequence $\{x_{n_k}\}$ (divergent in $\overline{X}$) contained in $X$.
(Of course, closure is with respect to $M$ endowed with the metric topology.)

I would guess it is, for every sequence in $\bar X$ we can build a very close sequense in $X$

Not any sequence. It's not difficult to make an example $M$, $X$ and $x_n$ where the sequence is wholly contained in $\overline X\setminus X$.

@Arthur yes, I'll edit that.

@RT1 That's my guess too, I just don't know how to prove it.

Take $M=(0,\infty)\subset \mathbb R$, $X=M\cap \mathbb Q$. Lastly, take the sequence $x_n=\sqrt{2}/n$.

This is a bit of an awkward phrasing. Your question seems to be equivalent to just "... show there is a Cauchy sequence in $X$ which does not converge in $\overline X$" (in which case that's the sequence and the subsequence). To show this, you should do what RT1 says and take a Cauchy sequence in $\overline X$ which does not converge and approximate it using a sequence in $X$, then argue that if two sequences approximate each other, then if one converges, so must the other, and that if one is Cauchy, so is the other.

@IzaakvanDongen Thanks, this is very helpful (and, yes, the phrasing was awkward).
